# Using a variables information in other classes / Flutter

Tags: class, flutter, dart

Thank you so much for reading and helping me out.

I'm currently building an app, where the user has to create a Card, which then will be displayed on the homepage inside a list. My problem is that I cant send the information of the two variables which save the user's input (name & birthday date) to the finished Card.

The desired variables which I want to navigate are contentname and contentbirthday.

Here's the part where the user enters the pieces of information:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'constants.dart';

class CardBasic extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CardBasicState createState() => _CardBasicState();
}

class _CardBasicState extends State<CardBasic> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
          0.58, //<-- set height of the card
      child: FirstCardCreation(
        //<-- new widget
        name: 'Erick Holz',
        birthday: '08.12.1998',
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstCardCreation extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final String birthday;

  const FirstCardCreation({
    Key key,
    @required this.name,
    @required this.birthday,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Color(0xFFef9a9a),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      elevation: 8,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32)),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          Expanded(
            child:
                FirstCardContent(contentname: name, contentbirthday: birthday),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstCardContent extends StatelessWidget {
  String contentname;
  String contentbirthday;

  FirstCardContent(
      {Key key, @required this.contentname, @required this.contentbirthday})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              decoration: kNameInput,
              onChanged: (value1) {
                contentname = value1;
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              decoration: kBirthdayInput,
              onChanged: (value2) {
                contentbirthday = value2;
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Later on, I want the user to add another input, that's why I created a separate finishedCard. But first of all, I would like to be able to create this finished card without the third input for general functionality. (In the future, my App should work like this: User presses the Button 'new' on the homescreen -> gets directed to the card creation, where he/she gives the name and birhtday as an input -> user taps the next button -> gets directed to the next site where the third and last input gets entered -> user presses finish and the user gets redirected to the homescreen, where the finished Card gets displayed inside a list.)

Heres the Code of the finished Card where I want the information of the variables contentname & contentbirthday from above getting stored inside the variables finalname & finalbirthday:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'real_new_card.dart';
import 'real_new_algorithm_card.dart';

class CardFinish extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CardFinishState createState() => _CardFinishState();
}

class _CardFinishState extends State<CardFinish> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height:
          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5, //<-- set height of the card
      child: FinalCardCreation(),
    );
  }
}

class FinalCardCreation extends StatelessWidget {
  final String finalname;
  final String finalbirthday;

  const FinalCardCreation({
    Key key,
    @required this.finalname,
    @required this.finalbirthday,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Color(0xFFef9a9a),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      elevation: 8,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32)),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          Expanded(
            child: FinalCardContent(
              name: finalname,
              birthday: finalbirthday,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FinalCardContent extends StatelessWidget {
  String name;
  String birthday;
  FinalCardContent({Key key, @required this.name, @required this.birthday})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              '$name',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 50.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              '$birthday',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 50.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help. I hope I formatted everything correctly.
Maybe my general approach is completely false.
If you have a better idea to let the user create a card with this functionality, which than gets displayed on a new card I would be very interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry but maybe you can show some code that dosen't work. The explanation is in my eyes not quite helpful. 
The only thing I noticed is that there are variables missing

```dart
child: FinalCardCreation(/*name and birthday here*/);
```

as you set that these fields are required.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. I want the information of the variables contentname and contentbirthday inside the Finalcardcreation. But I cant say: finalname: contentname, finalbirthday: contentbirthday.